# Как сделать архив всей БД Oracle, или отдельных таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle

Как скопировать всю базу Oracle со всеми таблицами для переноса на другой сервер, и можно ли копировать по отдельным таблицам (если можно то подскажите как)?

Дополнение:
слить таблички `CUSTOMERS` и `SALESREPS` из схемы `MILLER`:

```
..\.bat->

set nls_lang=russian_cis.ru8pc866
exp.EXE USERID=miller/kolobok@proba  TABLES=(CUSTOMERS, SALESREPS) FILE=c:\ORACLE\Tmiller.dat 
LOG=C:\ORACLE\Tmiller.LOG
```

А именно, не понятно что это такое `kolobok@proba` и с .bat файлами не совсем дружу. 
Как правильно сделать старт - так `.bat->` или всё же, так  `..\.bat->`, после сохранить с разрешением .bat и выполнить с terminal?

Comment: В гугле вбейте "oracle exp". Вот первое что находится http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?131

Comment: @ Разъясните дополнение в вопросе

Comment: лучше не ставьте такой дурацкий nls_lang, попробуйте выгрузить не указывая. У вас в базе наверняка UTF8 и в cp866 он один к одному может не перевестись. Для напачала саму строку `exp userid=...` тупо в терминале попробуйте. Если захотите автоматизировать на будущее, тогда .bat сделаете и в него это напишите. userid=пользователь/пароль@сервер. Если сервер локальный, то @сервер можно опустить

Comment: @Mike Сервер я могу и по ip задать ? Например (@192.168.1.3) ???

Comment: Нет, только имена указанные в tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [*Data Pump Export*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html). Выполните в окне терминала:

```
expdp miller/kolobok@probа tables=CUSTOMERS,SALESREPS directory=datapump_dir dumpfile=Tmiller.dat logfile=Tmiller.LOG
```

В праметре `directory` необходимо указать объект каталога определённый в БД, а не строку с путём к каталогу.

PS чтобы избежать перекодировку non-ASCII символов, в `nls_lang` необходимо указать кодировку, установленную в БД.